# O que o @at-root faz?

Tags: sass

Bom eu utilizei o tradutor pra ler [está documentação do SASS](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#at-root) e não entendi o que ele pode fazer...Então:

- O que o `@at-root` faz?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@at-root` é uma diretiva . Ela funciona pra '*saltar*' de onde você aninhou em seu Sass para um nível superior.

Por exemplo, você pode usá-lo assim:

```scss
h1 {
    font-size: 16px;
    @at-root {
        header {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 98%;
        }
    }
}
```

E o resultado é assim:

```
h1 {
    font-size: 16px;
}

header {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 98%;
}
```

[Fonte](http://alwaystwisted.com/articles/2014-03-08-using-sass-33s-at-root-for-piece-of-mind)